# Saving passwords decryptable for later usage

Tags: hash, aes

I'm in a situation where I **need to** calculate a hash of the result of the password in plain text plus some random chars representing a session. The gained hash will be compared to another hash that is received by the opponent. The problem is, that I only get the full hash from the opponent which can **only** be regenerated (or rebuild) with the plain text password.

What is the best practice in this situation? I thought of a algorithm such as AES for saving passwords in a persistent storage to decrypt it later but since I'm operating with the plain text passwords, it might not be very secure and another aspect would be the fact that I operate with sensitive information at this point. Salting seems also impossible.

Comment: Don't keep them in plaintext. You may want to read this... http://security.stackexchange.com/questions/63392/what-is-a-good-analogy-to-explain-why-passwords-should-be-hashed-to-a-layman/63421#63421

Comment: @Paddy I wouldn't but it seems you don't got me right. I'd like to store them hashed, salted or whatever but though I need them in plain text for later usage.

Answer (score 2):

**Hashes** are not meant to be reversed, and so there is no way you use a hash algorithm to protect a password and see the plain-text later.

What you can do is use a proper encryption algorithms or public and private keys to encrypt and decrypt the passwords, for example PGP.

Answer (score 2):

I would **highly** recommend you look at redesigning your solution to be able to use a hash, rather than either work with anything other than a one-way hash.

If you absolutely need to work with the cleartext password, it should be encrypted using a a high level library like NaCl (http://nacl.cr.yp.to/).  Symmetric vs. public-key encryption will be a function of your trust boundaries.

I want to emphasize that this is a **very bad** solution.  It's very easy to screw up a cryptosystem, even with a high level library.  Crypto is like WarGames:  The only way to win is not to play.

Comment: No, I'm not able to use a hash. I used to store the passwords as SHA hashes before but since my opponent is a network client which generates a hash based on the plain text password it's just not possible to store them as hash anymore. Thanks for your answer though, I already took a look into symmetric encryption and played a bit with AES that is making great in my case.